# UDP multiple client receiving from same source

Tags: sockets, udp

I have a question where 2 or more client on host A try to receive from host B with exactly the same address and port number.

Suppose we have host A and there are 2 thread running on it. A.thread_a sends a packet to B port xxxx. Then it does recvfrom(B, xxxx). At the same time, A.thread_b does the same recvfrom() call with same IP and port number. B, after receiving request from A.thread_a, sends data by sendto(A, yyyy). Who would receive the response, A.thread_a or A.thread_b?

Comment: Networking version of undefined behaviour:(

Comment: @MartinJames as in one shouldn't do this in the first place?

Comment: indeed.  If you want to multiplex message-streams from multiple threads, you should put some sort of originator-ID in the message and have the peer return it in the response.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to multiplex message-streams from multiple threads, you should put some sort of originator-ID in the message and have the peer return it in the response. –  Martin James